# pm.sendRequest is working after the for loop iteration is completed even though the request is inside the loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, postman

I'm trying to trigger a "pm.sendRequest" inside a for loop and the request is getting sent only after the iteration is completed, though I have kept the request inside the loop.

This is how my code looks like in the test section,

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const requestObject = {
        url: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
        method: "GET",
        header: "Content-Type:application/json",
    };

    console.log(i);

    pm.sendRequest(requestObject, (err, res) => {
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

The "i" which is getting printed inside the pm.sendRequest is alwas printed as 5.

Could you please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

pm.sendRequest() is an asynchronous function it calls the callback which get resolved as when it requires

THere is no order for this

so inside forloop the function call is initiated but you get the output after the forloop gets completed